# Why is my MySQL SELECT statement with ORDER BY so slow even though an INDEX is on the column?

Tags: mysql, indexing, sql-order-by

I have a `movies` table. It has 1.3 million rows in it.

The table has an `INDEX` on the `title` column, order `asc`, length `255`.

The `title` column itself is a `VARCHAR(1000)`.

Even with that setup, the following query takes 8 second to run. Anyone ideas or shots in the dark as to why this may be? I'm stumped because it seems like such a basic problem to solve.

```
SELECT title
FROM movies 
ORDER BY title
LIMIT 150000, 50000
```

When I take out the `ORDER BY`, the query is super fast (0.05 seconds):

```
SELECT title
FROM movies 
LIMIT 150000, 50000
```

Comment: Because of the `limit`.  The database engine needs to go through 150,000 rows.

Comment: @GordonLinoff actually limit is 50000

Comment: I agree that `LIMIT` is also part of the slowdown, but the time it's taking is ridiculous, especially when you raise the offset to something like `500000` (which ups the time to 30 seconds on the query). What are some solutions to speed it up?

Comment: You may have some issues with the table itself. Please recreate the table and see if the time changes

Comment: @EthanAllen could you please do `explain select ...` and post the output please? If the `explain` isn't using the index for any reason you can provide hint like so: `select ... from moves use index (idx_indexname) order...`

Answer (score 2):

Edit:  prefix index is a better name than partial index I used.

Since your index is a partial index, MySQL may not use it for the order by and still have to sort the values by their full lengths.

Let's try this small sample:

```
 create table o1 (a varchar(10));

 insert into o1 values('test1'),('test2'),('test3'),('tes1');
 create index oindex on o1 (a);
 explain select a from o1 order by a;
```

MySQL is using index for the order by.

```
     # id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
     '1', 'SIMPLE', 'o1', 'index', NULL, 'oindex', '103', NULL, '8', 'Using index'
```

Now, re-create a partial index:

```
 drop index oindex on o1;
 create index oindex on o1 (a (2) );
 explain select a from o1 order by a;
```

MySQL is now trying "filesort".

```
 # id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
 '1', 'SIMPLE', 'o1', 'ALL', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '8', 'Using filesort'
```

For searching, partial index is helpful since MySQL can just drop those values 
not completely matched. For ORDER BY, MySQL may have no such luck. In above case, even I create a "partial index" for the max. length of column, MySQL is still not using the index for ORDER BY.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with performance is the offset value expressed in the `limit` clause.  If you are reading through the table, then you can store the values and use a `>` before the `order by`:

```
select title
from movies
where title > $title
order by title
limit 50000;
```

If `$title` is the title at row 150,000 then this should go fast.  Based on the results from this query, you would reset `$title` for the next query.

I am surprised that relatively few rows takes tens of seconds.  It should go faster once the index is in memory.  One additional complicating factor is that the `title` might be long -- so the index might be occupying many tens or hundreds of megabytes.  That is still not *that* big, but it would introduce a noticeable delay.

Answer (score 0):

To search on something like a `title`, you would be much better off using `FULLTEXT` and `MATCH(...) AGAINST(...)`.